# Perl: cpan force install not working in single command

Tags: perl, cpan

I want to `force install` a perl module. When I do this, the installation succeeds:

```
cpan shell -- CPAN exploration and modules installation (v2.00)
Enter 'h' for help.

cpan[1]> force install Net::DNS::SEC
```

But when I do this, it fails:

```
root@ubuntu:~# cpan force install Net::DNS::SEC

Warning: Cannot install force, don't know what it is.
Try the command

    i /force/ 

...
...

Running make install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
```

I need to run the `cpan force install` in a single command. How do I proceed?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Please try `cpan -fi Net::DNS::SEC`

**What the flags mean:**

> - `f`: Force the specified action, when it normally would have failed. Use this to install a module even if its tests fail. When you use this option, `-i` is not optional for installing a module when you need to force it.
> - `i`: Install the specified modules.

`cpan -h` would provide you more details.

Answer (score 6):

use the `-f` option

From `man cpan`:

> `-f`  Force the specified action, when it normally would have failed. Use this to install a module even if its tests fail. When you use this
>   option, `-i` is not optional for installing a module when you need to
>   force it:
>
> ```
>                % cpan -f -i Module::Foo
> ```